# How can I avoid the ',' using OPENROWSET or BULK INSERTION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulk, openrowset

I have to read and insert into a table i already have in sql server 2005 i have to read a txt file that has more than 1million of records, it worked great using this method:

```
set @variable=' 

insert into table(row1)
select * from OPENROWSET(''MSDASQL'',''Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DEFAULTDIR='+@path+';rowDTERMINATOR = \n;'',''SELECT * FROM '+@fileName+''')                     
'
EXEC(@variable)
```

the problem is that some records has a ',' in the middle of the name of the client for example:

> david,steven abril pulecio

and this method insert that in the table like this:

> |david|

so how can i use this method or maybe use bulk insertion and evite that it cut the records when they have a ',' ?

Comment: Do your input files have the datafields quoted?

Comment: so you have comma separated file but in some cases `,` is used to separate the name instead of separating the fields? If you count that comma as separate field, do you have same number of fields or different?

Comment: yeah the comma is only in some cases and when a record has it that fucntion separate the row in an other field it doesnt matter if the name is inserted in the table with the comma i can handle that later i just need it to be inserted help please

Comment: Does `...,david,steven abril pulecio,...` actually look like this in your text file: `...,"david,steven abril pulecio",...`?

Comment: no it doesnt have any quoted marks